# Handle form data by myself

Tags: php, symfony

I built a form with createFormBuilder

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($post)
        ->add("name", TextType::class, array("label"=>"Article Title"))
        ->add("content", TextareaType::class, array("label"=>"Article Content"))
        ->add("categories",
            EntityType::class,
            array(
                "class" => Category::class,
                "choice_label" => "name",
                "multiple" => true,
                "label" => "Article Category",
                "required" => false
            )
        )
        ->add("attachments", TextType::class, array("required"=>false))
        ->add("submit", SubmitType::class, array("label"=>"Add new article"))
        ->getForm();
```

the "attachments" variable is an entity variable, I want to get a json string from the form and search the database by myself, like this:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$attachmentsRepository = $em->getRepository(Attachment::class);
$attachments = $post->getAttachments();
$json = json_decode($attachments);
$dataSize = sizeof($json);
for ($i = 0; $i < $dataSize; $i ++) {
    $attachment = $attachmentsRepository->find($json[$i]->getId());
    $post->addAttachments($attachment);
}
$em->persist($post);
$em->flush();
```

However, there is the error hint said that:

> Could not determine access type for property "attachments" in class
>   "App\Entity\Post".

I don't know how to solve this problem, if I add a @ORM\Column(type="string") in my Entity the json string will also be stored, I think this is not a good solution.

How do I modify my code?

Comment: Long shot, but is $attachments actually filled with attachments? Are you sure its not null/undefined? Also, attachments usually dont work if the form doesn't have enctype="multipart/form-data" on it

Comment: Can you shows us your `Post` entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all to get rid of the error you need to add `mapped => false` to the field options of your `attachments` field.

If the `attachments` fields is configured as a mapped field the form component will look for a `setAttachments()` method or a *public* property `attachments` in your `Post` Entity to set the value - which do not exist in your `Post` entity. That's why you get the error message:

> Could not determine access type for property "attachments" in class "App\Entity\Post".

In order to transform the submitted JSON string to `Attachment` entities yourself you need a custom **data transformer**!

A good example how create and use a data transformer can be found in the documentation chapter [How to Use Data Transformers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html).

A clean solution would involve the `attachments` field being a `CollectionType` of `EntityType`, sending the whole form as a JSON POST request and using i.e `FOSRestBundle`'s  `fos_rest.decoder.jsontoform` body listener to decode the JSON request to a form.

The documentation for FOSRestBundle's body listener support can be found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/body_listener.html).